# Xamarin Android: Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Trying to start a project (Xamarin Android) of another developer. 
The application is compiled successfully, first view shown correctly, it's okay.
But after a moment, then I get an error:

```
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart
```

Visual studio doesn't show any more information about the error, the debugger points to an empty string in MvxSimpleIoCContainer class.

Before opening the project reinstall VS, Xamarin, Android SDK etc.
This project is absolutely correct, on another computer was working perfectly and without this exception. Unfortunately i have no access to those computer.

I will be glad to any prompts.

Error mesage:

[image]

Visual Studio after clicking "break":

[image]

Comment: What does your Setup.cs and App.cs file look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,my problem was in the core'dll' app.cs

```
namespace Core
{
    public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();


            RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
```

I had no `RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();` line, change to use your first view.

Comment: I solved the problem that was in the Xamarin.iOS-project. 
I really did not understand what iOS has to do with Android, considering that I set in the build setting to to build iOS-project.